# how to prevent gnuplot from stretching the plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have variable data that represents geographic boundaries.  We produce a report that contains an image of the boundaries.  This image is fixed at 700x500.  I'd like the boundaries to be plotted without being stretched.  Centered would be awesome, but not necessary.

Here is a sample data set:

```
-87.6947 39.6481
-87.6949 39.6395
-87.7024 39.6375
-87.7137 39.6403
-87.7140 39.6345
-87.7128 39.6284
-87.7059 39.6263
-87.7047 39.6228
-87.7104 39.6222
-87.7114 39.6159
-87.7157 39.6115
-87.7200 39.6056
-87.7191 39.6013
-87.7121 39.6020
-87.7043 39.6009
-87.7037 39.5925
-87.6900 39.5920
-87.6863 39.6004
-87.6772 39.6028
-87.6700 39.6060
-87.6688 39.6152
-87.6696 39.6205
-87.6738 39.6212
-87.6756 39.6278
-87.6737 39.6340
-87.6779 39.6396
-87.6836 39.6441
-87.6868 39.6490
-87.6947 39.6481
-87.6947 39.6481

-87.7101 40.0760
-87.7173 40.0671
-87.7100 40.0588
-87.6959 40.0606
-87.6886 40.0645
-87.6700 40.0638
-87.6471 40.0639
-87.6470 40.0494
-87.6528 40.0434
-87.6452 40.0354
-87.6394 40.0199
-87.6396 39.9918
-87.6437 39.9884
-87.6458 39.9753
-87.6366 39.9653
-87.6230 39.9724
-87.6183 39.9787
-87.6240 39.9891
-87.6348 39.9932
-87.6359 40.0209
-87.6274 40.0296
-87.6294 40.0403
-87.6294 40.0503
-87.6279 40.0646
-87.6258 40.0764
-87.6221 40.0795
-87.6227 40.0806
-87.6341 40.0810
-87.6327 40.0858
-87.6301 40.0920
-87.6269 40.1009
-87.6259 40.1057
-87.6314 40.1052
-87.6372 40.1049
-87.6437 40.1050
-87.6517 40.1047
-87.6561 40.1047
-87.6577 40.1014
-87.6562 40.0960
-87.6519 40.0932
-87.6493 40.0890
-87.6445 40.0858
-87.6377 40.0848
-87.6375 40.0804
-87.6462 40.0809
-87.6456 40.0768
-87.6427 40.0718
-87.6367 40.0708
-87.6381 40.0660
-87.6930 40.0657
-87.6958 40.0694
-87.6985 40.0728
-87.7033 40.0750
-87.7101 40.0760
-87.7101 40.0760
```

Here are the gnuplot commands:

```
unset logscale xy
set term png font arial 8 size 700,500
set output 'map.png'
plot 'boundary.dat' with lines
```

Here is what I get:
[image: stretched]

Here is what I'd like to get (only centered on a 700x500 canvas):
[image: unstretched]

Comment: Try `set size ratio -1` which tells gnuplot to use same unit for both axes

Comment: genius.  @Christoph - worked like a charm  (you should post that as an answer)